# Limit SQL recursion to single row per recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have two tables:

**Event (EventId INT, StartDate DATETIME)**

```
 EventId | StartDate
-----------------------------
 1000    | 2021-04-05 20:32:00
```

**Cause (CauseId INT, EventId INT, Minutes INT)**

```
 CauseId | EventId | Minutes
-----------------------------
 5000    | 1000    | 20
 5001    | 1000    | 27
 5002    | 1000    | 30
```

For each combination of `EventId` and `CauseId` I need to generate a `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

```
 EventId | CauseId | Minutes | StartDate           | EndDate
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1000    | 5000    | 20      | 2021-04-05 20:32:00 | 2021-04-05 20:52:00
 1000    | 5001    | 27      | 2021-04-05 20:52:00 | 2021-04-05 21:19:00
 1000    | 5002    | 30      | 2021-04-05 21:19:00 | 2021-04-05 21:49:00
```

`LAG` doesn't seem like it would work, I would need to reference the previous rows calculation to generate the `StartDate` and the same rows calculation to generate the `EndDate`.

```
-- Not allowed.
SELECT e.EventId, c.CauseId, c.Minutes,
       LAG(CalculatedEndDate, 1, DATEADD(MI, c.Minutes, e.StartDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY e.EventId ORDER BY c.CauseId) AS CalculatedStartDate,
       DATEADD(MI, c.Minutes, CalculatedStartDate) AS CalculatedEndDate
FROM Event e
INNER JOIN Cause c ON c.EventId = e.EventId
```

A recursive CTE doesn't seem to work either, I'm not allowed to use `TOP` or an `AGGREGATE` and don't see how to handle the rows one at a time without it. e.g.

```
-- Initial query
UNION ALL
-- Removed for brevity
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.EventId = e.EventId
INNER JOIN Cause c ON c.CauseId  = (SELECT MIN(CauseId) FROM Cause WHERE CauseId > cte.CauseId AND EventId = e.EventId)
```

or

```
-- Initial query
UNION ALL
-- Removed for brevity
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.EventId = e.EventId
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM Cause
             WHERE EventId = e.EventId AND CauseId > cte.CauseId
             ORDER BY CauseId ASC) c
```

Comment: can you post teh complete code, with that bits it is hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the window function `sum() over()` would help here

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=547efd2c15c4ffab3050b3db2ee8d1de)**

```
Select A.*
      ,StartDate = dateadd(MINUTE
                          ,sum(minutes) over (partition by A.EventID order by A.CauseID rows unbounded preceding ) 
                           - A.Minutes
                          ,B.StartDate)
     ,EndDate    = dateadd(MINUTE
                          ,sum(minutes) over (partition by A.EventID order by A.CauseID rows unbounded preceding ) 
                          ,B.StartDate)
 From Cause A
 Join Event B on A.EventID=B.EventID
```

**Results**

```
CauseId EventId Minutes StartDate               EndDate
5000    1000    20      2021-04-05 20:32:00.000 2021-04-05 20:52:00.000
5001    1000    27      2021-04-05 20:52:00.000 2021-04-05 21:19:00.000
5002    1000    30      2021-04-05 21:19:00.000 2021-04-05 21:49:00.000
```

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` would be wise

Comment: @Charlieface Correct assuming CauseID is NOT unique.

Comment: Even if it is unique, it's still more efficient to use `ROWS`. See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/window-functions-in-sql-server-part-3-questions-of-performance/ for example

Comment: `CauseId` is a PK if it's relevant.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller It helps, charlieface is correct.   rows unbounded preceding is more performant